# How to define global variables in stencil.js/tsx?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsx, stenciljs

How can I define global variables in a Stencil.js component?

```
@ClickOutside()
  someMethod() {
    let editable = this.el.querySelector('.editable');
    if (this.el.classList.contains('is-open')) {
      this.el.classList.toggle('is-open');
      editable.setAttribute('contenteditable',
        editable.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');
    }
  }

  openToolbar() {
    let editable = this.el.querySelector('.editable');
    if (editable.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'true') {
      return
    }
    this.el.classList.toggle('is-open');
    editable.setAttribute('contenteditable',
      editable.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');
  }
```

This works as expected, but I am repeating myself in two separate functions. I would like to define the first let variable outside so I can use it in both functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to the state as follows.

```
    @State() editable;

    componentWillLoad() {
       this.editable = this.el.querySelector('.editable');
    }

    @ClickOutside()
        someMethod() {
            if (this.el.classList.contains('is-open')) {
                this.el.classList.toggle('is-open');
                editable.setAttribute('contenteditable',
                editable.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');
             }
        }

        openToolbar() {
            if (editable.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'true') {
                return
            }
            this.el.classList.toggle('is-open');
            editable.setAttribute('contenteditable',
            editable.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');
        }
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Is this considered a hack or the correct way to do? I’m not really familiar with JSX and States, but since the State is not going to change (and thus no re-render), I assume it is alright?

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Not a workaround or hack. :)

Comment: Hey, im getting an error doing that:
ReferenceError: editable is not defined

If I try using this.editable it also gives me an error

Comment: Ah you have found the solution right :) If you want to set it before the first render, initiate it in componentWillLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, based on Koga's tips:

```
@State() editable;

  componentDidLoad() {
    this.editable = this.el.querySelector('.editable');
  }

  @ClickOutside()
  someMethod() {
    if (this.el.classList.contains('is-open')) {
      this.el.classList.toggle('is-open');
      this.editable.setAttribute('contenteditable',
        this.editable.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');
    }
  }

  openToolbar() {
    if (this.editable.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'true') {
      return
    }
    this.el.classList.toggle('is-open');
    this.editable.setAttribute('contenteditable',
      this.editable.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');
  }
```